# Remove est from date value in ssis derived column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have date in format of 22-Mar-2023 08.01.44 PM(EST).

I want to remove the `(Est)` part of the date but it fails.

Trying this code but it doesn't work :

```
SUBSTRING([Data Date], 1, 2) + "-" + 
(SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "JAN" ? "01" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "FEB" ? "02" : 
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "MAR" ? "03" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "APR" ? "04" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "MAY" ? "05" : 
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "JUN" ? "06" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "JUL" ? "07" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "AUG" ? "08" :
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "SEP" ? "09" : 
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "OCT" ? "10" : 
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "NOV" ? "11" : 
 SUBSTRING([Data Date], 4, 3) == "DEC" ? "12")  + "-"  + 
SUBSTRING([Data Date], 8, 4)
```

Looks like some syntax error

> Expression cannot be parsed

Comment: Just replace using Replace function `(DT_WSTR, 20)REPLACE([Data Date], "(EST)", "")`

All occurrences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16) Expression shall work for you in SSIS Derived Column transformation

replace all occurrences using :

```
(DT_WSTR, 20)REPLACE([Data Date], "(EST)", "")
```

OR
The below one using [LEFT Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/left-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
LEFT([Data Date],LEN([Data Date])-5)
```

This will extract the left part of the `Data Date` column excluding the last 5 characters